# I started a bounty, but I don't like the answers!

Tags: discussion, bounty

If I am unsatisfied by the answers on a question with a bounty that is set to expire soon, can I cancel the bounty? What am I supposed to do to get better answers??

Comment: Point of order: you can't cancel a bounty but mods can for you.

Comment: IMHO you can bump it back to the main page with a trivial edit on the last day if you haven't gotten anything. Otherwise, it might just be that our current users...don't know!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166172/162102

Comment: Thanks, @Monica Chellio. I hear both sides, but on a smaller site, I think a veto option might come in handy. Even if just a downvote.

Comment: I agree -- the bounty-giver ought to be able to say "no, not that answer", even if it means a forfeit (like happens if you get no answers at all...been there).

Comment: @Monica Cellio, I mean, we _are_, first and foremost, a community site, and the idea is to allow the community to crowdsource the best answer. But even so, sometimes (ok, LOADS of times) a half-answer or even a non-answer gets votes, and then what are you supposed to do?

Comment: Participating in that MSO question may be the best path to getting this.

Comment: This is why I stopped offering bounties, for the most part. I do like the idea of awarding bounties after the fact.

Comment: That's part of the risk of offering up a bounty, though -- it's possible the results you receive will not be what you had hoped for.

Comment: @DoubleAA, can you please cancel the one I have open that hasn't got ANY answers to date? I don't need the points back, but I'd be annoyed if someone swooped in with a terrible answer and claimed it (even half of it).